# Implement drag and drop in nsviewcontroller

Tags: objective-c, macos, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to catch drag and drop event in nsviewcontroller, but

> draggingEntered

is not called .

here is my code :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[self.view registerForDraggedTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSTIFFPboardType, NSFilenamesPboardType, nil]];

[super viewDidLoad];

// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (NSDragOperation)draggingEntered:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender{
    return NSDragOperationCopy;
}

- (BOOL)prepareForDragOperation:(id )sender {
    return YES;
}
```

I have add custom view , but it doesn't get event too :

```
   @implementation MyView
- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    if (self) {
        [self registerForDraggedTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: NSColorPboardType, NSFilenamesPboardType, nil]];
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSDragOperation)draggingEntered:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender {

    return NSDragOperationNone;
}

@end
```

Comment: You are simply implementing NSDragOperation on a wrong class.  What is NSViewController for?

Comment: I'm just testing drag and drop, have one view controller and inside this vc I registered dragged typed for view . I should use custom view?

Comment: Hey, your are right ... I have remove overrides from view controller so my custom view now can get drag and drop events.